# How to setup go-mmproxy

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy

So, I'm have HA Proxy setup, and I want to use the proxy protocol to send my ssh requests, as well as other requests to other TCP services like a minecraft server. I read the article [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/mmproxy-creative-way-of-preserving-client-ips-in-spectrum/), but I didn't understand how to setup mmproxy (I installed [go-mmproxy](https://github.com/path-network/go-mmproxy) as regular mmproxy wouldn't compile). Could someone please guide me on how to setup mmproxy, and my HA Proxy server sends the packets to the tailscale ip of this machine (100.91.56.39), so that anything that is forward retains the original IP?

Result of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.136  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:8300  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:01:83:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1079791  bytes 614920269 (586.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 40186  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 413958  bytes 246039170 (234.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 297  bytes 25587 (24.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 297  bytes 25587 (24.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tailscale0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1280
        inet 100.91.56.39  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 100.91.56.39
        inet6 fe80::1035:a7c6:1f21:aa97  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:625b:3827  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 158436  bytes 18055203 (17.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 193670  bytes 203374669 (193.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The result of `ifconfig` on the server hosting HA Proxy:

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 10.0.0.133  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::17ff:fe17:895f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:00:17:17:89:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1154820  bytes 1170789775 (1.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 998018  bytes 483441528 (483.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 21266  bytes 2650809 (2.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21266  bytes 2650809 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tailscale0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1280
        inet 100.101.205.54  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 100.101.205.54
        inet6 fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:6265:cd36  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::50e9:4406:1131:2f21  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 257333  bytes 237708378 (237.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 199652  bytes 21930487 (21.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My HA Proxy config:

```
frontend ssh-elixir-vahin2
    bind 0.0.0.0:23
    mode tcp
    log global    
    default_backend     server1-ssh
    timeout client 0

backend server1-ssh
    mode tcp
    timeout server 0
    server ssh 100.91.56.39:22
```